# Variable doesn't get passed to Ajax call : undefined variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

*I've edited this question from the original OP to better represent my issue.*

How can I pass the variable `data-uid` with AJAX ?

Right now the variable doesnt get passed.

`var uid = $(this).data("uid");`  doesn't work = undefined

`var uid = '199';`  gets passed. works.

is it possible to have something like : `var uid = $uid;`  ?

HTML

```
 <form>
  <fieldset>
  <textarea id="post_form" type="text" data-uid="<?php echo $uid ?>"/></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="add" value="Update" name="submit" />OK</button>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {
    var boxval = $("#post_form").val();
    var uid = $(this).data("uid");  // this needs to be changed
    var dataString = 'post_form=' + boxval + '&uid=' + uid;
    if (boxval == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,

            success: function(html) {
            parent.html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show the related html ?

Comment: what does the `.like` element look like?

Comment: you're perform POST instead of GET, use get and `url: "delete.php?"+dataString `

Comment: Post some of your HTML code and make sure there aren't any other elements with the same class name that could be interfering.

Comment: @karthikr just edited my question.

Comment: is your JS uid `undefined`? In that case you should double check your html.

Comment: yes, the variable is undefined when i inspect the element in the console

Comment: @IlyaBursov I've edited my question to make it more general, clearer. Hope you can help.

Comment: @ChHr how do you add new items? do you set data-id for them?

Comment: @IlyaBursov i add new items with add.php which works well. $uid here is the user's id (which i obtain with a GET['id'] at the top of my script. Now, i need to pass $uid through the form when it's submitted

Comment: @ChHr use `var uid = $('post_form').attr('data-uid');`

Comment: @IlyaBursov it works ! Thanks ! Feel free to add it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem in your code in:

`var uid = $(this).data("uid");`

you're trying to wrap `this` into jquery object, but it is button object in this context, then you're trying to obtain something unassigned from it

you shoud use:

`var uid = $('#post_form').attr('data-uid');`

or, you can add `<input type="hidden" name=... value=...` and get id from it, this is more general way

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your issue is with the data attribute that should be data-uid="somevalue" `<a href="#" class="like" id="1234" data-uid="7687687">Like</a>`.

Check this fiddle [to see if this solves your main problem](http://jsfiddle.net/KZYtn/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question. When the page is refreshed `data-id="<?php echo $uid ?>` echoes the right uid. The issue is during the AJAX callback: when a new item is added, `data-id` is undefined.

Comment: What does html parameter return? A new element?